# GridBag Layout fill the empty cells or skipped cells

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm really new to this. I'm still trying different examples.
Please correct me if I'm wrong. If I have the image below. [image]

with

```
Button 1:
gridx = 0; grid y = 0;

Button 2:
gridx = 1; grid y = 0;

Button 3:
gridx = 2; gridy = 1;
```

and I want to hava a blank area or cell between button2 and button3. I thought maybe I do it with insets or is there any correct way of doing this?

I'm still learning so I'm following this guide. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

I see components as objects in cells, how about the blank cells, what are they in gridbag layout perspective? how do I tell java that this is a blank cell? Should I always use the fill = GridbagConstraint.HOR.. ? I understand that widths are like spans or merged cells.

I hope you can better explain this. The things I haven't understood fully yet are weights and when I can extend a component further using gridx and gridy. Though I understand weights as spaces. I'm just looking for a practical explanation or comparison to html / excel

My questions are:

1. If i have 3 components on x's 0,1,2 will it not allow me to put the third component on like say, gridx=3 or gridx=5?
2. Given the 2 subpanels in the screenshot I included, how do i position the left panel to the upper left corner of top panel enclosing the 2 subpanels? Do i have to go straight to anchors??
3. Does the weighty always push other components up and weightx push left?
4. What is the most effective way of using fill()?

Comment: Hey I think this is just a small error in your writing of the question but don't you mean "`Button 3: gridx = 2; gridy = 1;`"? You went from 0, 1, and then right to 3 for `gridx`. The wouldn't correspond to the picture above.

Comment: Are you asking how to add black cells in between objects on the display?
(You are also asking for a clean cut example showing you what `weight` and `fill` do too, but just want to clarify the main question first)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, it's supposed to be 2,1

Comment: @Daniel H, i edited it with my questions i hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: Yes, insets are the correct way to place blank space between cells.  Weights specify how *extra* space is distributed amongst cells when the container is wider than their preferred widths or taller than their preferred heights;  a weight does not guarantee space between cells, and cells with the same weight are not guaranteed to have the same width or height.  Since each row/column has a flexible height/width, empty cells contribute no width/height at all and do not create space between populated cells.